# Libgdx game lags on better phones

Tags: android, libgdx, lag

I'm developing a candy crush game and it works just fine on desktop, my mobile (Honor9) and the one I'm using as emulator. But, for my surprise, it lags on my girlfriend's mobile, which is way better then mine (Samsung s10), when I'm doing the starting game animations (pieces falling to their position).

I believe the problem is not how I'm loading assets because it just lags on that specific animation.
Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you play sounds?

Comment: Yeah just figured out it's the sounds that are lagging on Samsung s10 :|

Comment: Check your sound files, convert them to ogg files all the same framerate. Try 44100 kHz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your sound files, convert them to ogg files all the same framerate. Try 44100 kHz.